# Can I create a UIPageControl / UIScrollview where the pages are larger than the screen size?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am writing an App where we want to have several pages in a UIPageControl/UIScrollView.  The problem is I need some space between each page - in other words, scrolling from page 1 to page 2 there is a visible gap between the pages.

I've tried doing this by setting the page's frames to be larger than the UIScrollView, but I can't seem to get this working.  Does anybody know if it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page size is always the same as the width of the scroll view. To make the pages larger than the visible area, you should make the scroll view itself a little larger, too. For example, if the width of the screen is 320 points, make the scroll view 340 points wide (10 points overhang on each side).

Comment: Thanks - I think I had tried everything but this - mainly just making the views I was scrolling bigger.  Seems to work as expected now...